# matching data from one worksheet column to another worksheet column

Tags: loops, vbscript, matching, vlookup, if-statement

I have two worksheets that have two columns of data. In column A of the Worksheets are the name of an item and in column B are the price of the item. Worksheet 1 has the price from last year and worksheet 2 has price from this year. The names of items in Worksheet 1 may or may not be in Worksheet 2.

I need a process that will match the names in each worksheet and if there is a match determine the price differential for that item. The price differential will go in column C in worksheet 2.

I have considered using an if-then function with a vlookup function but, I need to check for a match in all columns A from worksheet 1 and worksheet 2 for all the records. I believe a VB looping process may be more efficient.

Comment: Try [How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)

Answer (score 0):

Since it would appear to me you are only likely to require this once (or once a year) efficiency does not seem to be very significant, so formulae may serve.

Assuming labels (respectively: `Item_Name`  and `Price_O` in Sheet1, `Item_Name`, `Price_N` and `Diff` in Sheet2) in Row1 then the following formulae (copied down to suit) should indicate where there is no match (with `#N/A` or, if there is, the price change relative to last year:

In Sheet1 C2: `=IF(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)>0,"")`
In Sheet2 C2: `=B2-VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)`

---

Alternatively, a pivot table might provide a better overview, in combination with:

In Sheet2 H5: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(F5),ISBLANK(G5)),"No Match",G5-F5)` (copied down to suit).

1. In Sheet2 E1 call up the PivotTable wizard (Alt+D, P if required) , select Multiple consolidation ranges and PivotTable, Next.
2. Select I will create the page fields, Next.
3. In Range select or insert Sheet1!$A:$B, Add, then Sheet2!$A$B, Add, Next, select Existing worksheet and enter `=$E$3`, Finish.
4. Right click on table and if necessary change Σ Values from Count of Value to Sum of Value (by left clicking on Count of Value, left clicking on Value Field Settings… and selecting Sum in Summarize by), OK.
5. Right click on the table, left click on PivotTable Options, left click on Totals & Filters and if necessary untick Show grand totals for rows, OK.
6. If necessary, right click on `PriceN` in the table, Sort, Sort Z-A.

---

[image: SO12563000 example]